# Error performing git clone from azure devops pipeline task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a problem executing a pipeline in azure devops.
This task is part of my pipeline, as you can see it is an instruction to clone a repository.

```
- script: |   
    mkdir FOLDER_PUBLISH_AZURE
    git clone https://$(AZURE_DEPLOY_USERNAME):$env:MY_AZURE_DEPLOY_PASSWORD@develroomlabs-events.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/develroomlabs-events.git FOLDER_PUBLISH_AZURE
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
  displayName: 'Download SCM repo for pipeline '
  env:
    MY_AZURE_DEPLOY_PASSWORD: $(AZURE_DEPLOY_PASSWORD)
```

The result I get is as follows:

[image]

But the pipeline variables are well added, I did a test by directly adding username and password in the YAML file, but the result was the same.
What could be happening? Am I doing something wrong?

I do this same task of cloning a repository from a bitbucket pipeline and I have no problems.

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing that in Windows environment with **Microsoft-hosted windows agents** instead of **Micorosft-hosted Linux agents**.

I can reproduce same issue when using Linux environment, but it actually works well in windows environment. I think this issue could be related to that Linux has different behavior when treating url format like  `https://$AppName:xxx@sAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/AppName.git`...

(Something looks like [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/958125/using-google-repo-tool-with-devops-repositories.html),the behavior should have something to do with Linux server itself)